# Relating two variables to a function

Tags: functions

I have two variables x and y:

- x: can be from 0 to k where k is a constant.
- y: can be from 0 to infinity.

I'm trying to formulate a function f(x, y) that takes x and y and gives an output such that:

- f = 0, when x = 0
- f = 1, when x = k and y = 0
- f between 0 and 1 otherwise.

Can anyone give a hint on how to achieve this or if it can be done at all?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. When you ask a question, you are expected to show some effort. Since you need a hint, consider $f = x \times$ something

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE ! On this site, a community discusses about mathematics. On this basis, the other users will need to see what you have already tried, because any question can be answered in a lot of ways, and it's impossible to figure out what kind of answer you are expecting if you do not share your efforts with us. Please edit your question to include your work.

Comment: It is perfectly possible, if no other requirement is made, to give the following answer : $$\left\{\begin{array}{c}f(x,y)=0 \;\;\text{if $x=0$}, \\f(x,y)=1 \;\;\text{if $x=k$}, \\f(x,y)=1/\pi\;\; \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$ If $f$ needs to be continuous, continously differentiable, $\mathcal C^\infty$, you should clarify this point.

Answer (score 1):

Well the function $f(x,y)=\frac{2x}{k}\frac{e^y}{1+e^y}$

(This is a continuous function satisfies the criteria.)

Comment: No, when x=k and y does not equal to 0, f shouldn't give 1

Comment: @user2073081: In all fairness, though, you didn't say "strictly" between ...

Comment: @user2073081 Check edit

Comment: (After several formulas for continuous functions have been posted:) There are lots of formulas, so we could play this game all night. $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac {x}{(x-k)^2+y^2+k}$ also works (provided $k>0$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $$f(x,y) = \cases{0 & if $x=0$\cr 1 & if $x=k$ and $y=0$\cr 0.5 & otherwise\cr}$$
There are many others that will work as well.

Comment: I like this answer. It may look "minimum effort", but I think it really highlights how OP's question was far too broad.